# add header to strings by using the string itself

Tags: awk

I want to add a header t my input strings. The header should be `>` directly followed by the string and the number after the string separated with a `_`
To add a header I used this `awk '{print ">"$0;print}'`  However I dont kno how to add the number behind.

input:

```
CTTCTATGATGAATTTGATTGCATTGATCGTCTGACATGATAATGTATTT  2
AGAACGAAAGTCGGAGGTTCGAAGACGATC   14
TACCCTGTAGAACCGAANTTGT   1
TCCCTGTGGTCTAGTGGTTAGGATTCTGCGCTCTCACCGCCGCGGCCCGGG     2
GGGCCAGGATGAAACCTAATTTGAGTGGCCATCCATGGATGAGAAATGCGG 4
TAATACGGCCGGGTAATGATGGA 0
CCAGATGATGAACTTATTGACGGGCGGACAGAAACTGTGTGCTGATTGTCA 7240
CGCCCGATCTCGTCTGATCTCG  34
GCAGGGGTGGTTCAGTGGTAGAATTCTCGCC 3
```

output:

```
>CTTCTATGATGAATTTGATTGCATTGATCGTCTGACATGATAATGTATTT_2
 CTTCTATGATGAATTTGATTGCATTGATCGTCTGACATGATAATGTATTT
>AGAACGAAAGTCGGAGGTTCGAAGACGATC_14
 AGAACGAAAGTCGGAGGTTCGAAGACGATC
....
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk '{printf ">%s_%s\n %s\n",$1,$2,$1;}' file
>CTTCTATGATGAATTTGATTGCATTGATCGTCTGACATGATAATGTATTT_2
 CTTCTATGATGAATTTGATTGCATTGATCGTCTGACATGATAATGTATTT
>AGAACGAAAGTCGGAGGTTCGAAGACGATC_14
 AGAACGAAAGTCGGAGGTTCGAAGACGATC
>TACCCTGTAGAACCGAANTTGT_1
 TACCCTGTAGAACCGAANTTGT
>TCCCTGTGGTCTAGTGGTTAGGATTCTGCGCTCTCACCGCCGCGGCCCGGG_2
 TCCCTGTGGTCTAGTGGTTAGGATTCTGCGCTCTCACCGCCGCGGCCCGGG
>GGGCCAGGATGAAACCTAATTTGAGTGGCCATCCATGGATGAGAAATGCGG_4
 GGGCCAGGATGAAACCTAATTTGAGTGGCCATCCATGGATGAGAAATGCGG
>TAATACGGCCGGGTAATGATGGA_0
 TAATACGGCCGGGTAATGATGGA
>CCAGATGATGAACTTATTGACGGGCGGACAGAAACTGTGTGCTGATTGTCA_7240
 CCAGATGATGAACTTATTGACGGGCGGACAGAAACTGTGTGCTGATTGTCA
>CGCCCGATCTCGTCTGATCTCG_34
 CGCCCGATCTCGTCTGATCTCG
>GCAGGGGTGGTTCAGTGGTAGAATTCTCGCC_3
 GCAGGGGTGGTTCAGTGGTAGAATTCTCGCC
```

#### How it works

The awk script consists of a single command:

```
printf ">%s_%s\n %s\n",$1,$2,$1
```

By default, awk splits up input lines into fields based on white space.  So, For the first line for example, field 1 is `CTTCTATGATGAATTTGATTGCATTGATCGTCTGACATGATAATGTATTT` and field 2 is `2`.  The `printf` allows us to rearrange the input into the desired format.  For each input line, two lines are written.  The first one, with format `>%s_%s\n` writes `>` followed by field 1 followed by `_` followed by field 2 followed by a newline character.  The format for the second output line is`%s\n` which outputs a space followed by field one followed by a newline character.